# First line in a turtle animation is always shorter than the rest in python

Tags: python, python-turtle

No matter what I do, the first line drawn by my turtle is shorter than the rest. I've tried many variations of code but I can't find anyone with a similar problem. I set values for how far the turtle should go but it completely ignores the value on its first move. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

```
    import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
turtle = turtle.Turtle()

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-300, 250)
turtle.pendown()

for i in range (0, 500):

    turtle.forward(200)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(200)

wn.exitonclick()
```

[image: Turtle Issue]

As you can see in the picture, the first line (the top line) is about half as long as the second (the right line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the second `turtle.forward(200)`, you are drawing lines of length `400`. After you turn `90` let the next iteration draw the straight line, with your current code you are drawing one `200` line then proceeding to draw another `200` after you turn.

```
for i in range (0, 500):

    turtle.forward(200)
    turtle.right(90)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that in your loop, you move forward both at beginning and at the end.

So, the first time, it goes forward 200px, turns right 90°, and goes forward 200px again.
The next time, it starts drawing exactly where it stopped, so it moves forward another 200px, making the line twice as long as the first one. It then turns right 90°, and goes forward 200px, and so on.

To solve this problem, you should just move forward 400px and turn right 90° each time through the loop:

```
for i in range (0, 500):

    turtle.forward(400)
    turtle.right(90)
```

That should fix your issue!